# How to prevent the program being closed when it runs on the touch screen with full screen mode?

Tags: delphi, fullscreen, firemonkey, touchscreen

I am developing a mall guide program using the Firemonkey framework.The program runs on a touchscreen all-in-one machine without physical keyboard and mouse. The operating system is Windows 10.

This program runs in full screen mode (MainForm.FullScreen := true), and it is the only program that should be run on this machine!

But I found that even if my program is running in full screen mode (covering the Windows Start menu and taskbar), visitors can still toggle my program off by sliding their finger from the edge of the screen.

Is there any way to avoid this situation?

I recorded a demo video to illustrate this problem. As you can see, visitors can close or switch off my program more loosely:
[Demo video](https://youtu.be/BgDvKsu3l88)

Comment: this is not a problem on program level but on OS level. Use [kiosk mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app).

Comment: @whosrdaddy, thanks for the comment. This is the first time I've heard of the kiosk model and I will be learning it.